# Java file copy from one server to another

Tags: java, file-io

I want to copy one file from  system1 to system2. both these system are in the same network. the file is present in a shared folder in system1. i have a username and password to access that location.  how can i write a javacode to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your solution have to use plain Java? If not, it would be better to use existing file transfer utilities, like `scp` if you're using *nix computers.

If the answer to my question is yes, then [sockets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) are the way to go. Apache Commons libraries like [net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) and [io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) might also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

using sockets.  connect to system1. copy file, connect to system 2. paste file.  voila.

[An oracle tutorial on sockets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/)

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do it under *nix only. First you have to mount both shared folders. That should do either system administrator of your computer or you can do it in your program via FUSE ("File system in user space") and appropriate Samba plugins. And then you can copy required files as usual.